# Do LED lamps need a bulb?

Tags: led

I bought an LED light bulb on eBay, which unfortunately is too big for the lamp i want to put it in. If I would remove the glass bulb however, it would fit. My question is, does the lamp actually need the glass bulb, like a normal lightbulb does? Or is it there just for asthetic or maybe safety reasons?

The product in question is this one:

http://m.ebay.de/itm/3W-4W-5W-E14-E27-LED-Birne-Gluehbirne-Lampe-Leuchtmittel-Milch-Klar-Kerzen-Kugel-/331509865665?varId=540677165602&txnId=1163527699014

Comment: There may be lots of small reasons, but they're are all swamped by the "someone might get killed by electrocution" reason.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easiest/safest to simply buy a led bulb with a smaller form factor?

Comment: That would involve buying, which I'm trying to avoid :)

Comment: Thanks for all the feedback, I did remove the bulb and it works just fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short: No they don't.
There is three reasons (as I see it) that they have a glass bulb on LED-lamps:

1. It protects against dust.
2. To be more "pleasing" (i.e. look as ordinary/filament light bulbs).
3. The glass shields against any bare contacts that may be "live" when the lamp is turned on.

There's several types of LED-lamps that you can buy without any glass bulb, like:
http://www.ebay.com/itm/10-X-G4-SMD-26-LED-Warm-White-Home-Car-RV-Marine-Boat-Light-Bulbs-Lamps-DC12V-/351461500318?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_3&hash=item51d4bce59e
http://www.ebay.com/itm/E27-GU10-MR16-4W-5W-LED-SPOTLIGHT-SMD-110V-220V-12V-warm-cool-white-Bulb-Lamp-/360940873184?var=&hash=item5409c0a5e0

Just be careful when removing the glass, and avoid touching the lamp when it's on!

Comment: 4: It acts as a diffuser. LEDs can be very small and bright points of light that can damage your eyes when looked at directly. The glass envelope spreads out this light so that the bulb is safe to look at, at least long enough for your usual aversion response to bright light to kick in and move your gaze away. This response is not fast enough to avoid damage from a small and bright point of light like bare multi-watt illumination LEDs.

Comment: I picked this answer for being more involved.

Comment: There are also off-brand, bulb-less devices on the market that forgo safety.....

Answer (score 3):

Both safety and aesthetic.

It keeps fingers from touching the circuit which is most likely directly connected to the mains (no isolation). Removing it would create a serious safety hazard.